# Ionic Diagnostic Plugin always returns "DENIE_ALWAYS" on android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using Ionic 4 and all my IOS diagnostic permissions are working..

But on android if I request access to anything (lets say CAMERA for example).  It returns a DENIE_ALWAYS response.  If I go into the settings>app settings> permissions It is saying that the app doesn't need any permissions.  I've verified the permissions exist in the androidManifest.xml.  But I am unable to ever prompt to user for permissions.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Example code

```
   this.diagnostic.getCameraAuthorizationStatus()
    .then( async (status) => {
      debugger;
      if (status === this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED
        || status === this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED_WHEN_IN_USE) {
        this.appSettings.camera.enabled = true;
        this.updateAppSettings();
      } else if (status === this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED) {
        this.diagnostic.requestCameraAuthorization()
          .then((res) => {
           // HERE IS ALWAYS DENIE_ALWAYS WITHOUT EVER PROMPTING USER
            debugger;
            if (res === this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED
              || res === this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED_WHEN_IN_USE) {
              this.appSettings.camera.enabled = true;
              this.updateAppSettings();
            } else {
              this.appSettings.camera.enabled = false;
              this.updateAppSettings();
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer after hours of searching..

Under the platforms>android>AndroidManifest.xml you need to make sure this includes all your permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

But for some reason this AndroidManifest wasn't the same that was being used under

platforms > android> app> src > main> AndroidManifest.xml

And a build wasn't updating that file either. So I copied the correct AndroidManifest.xml to that path and it started working.

This was way harder than it should have been.. I don't know why adding and removing the platform or rebuilding wouldn't updating that manifest..

Comment: i have tried to check the folder. But there is no AndroidManifest.xml file inside platforms > android. File exists at platforms > android> app> src > main> AndroidManifest.xml This file is not containing the permission but node_modules > cordova-android > bin > templates > project > AndroidManifest.xml is containing the permission

Comment: @vbharath it's been months since I figured this out.. I just remember it being a nightmare.  It all came down to the permissions not being in the right place at the right time.

Comment: @caden311 Did you find the reason why the permissions are not getting added in manifest file?

Comment: @SanjaySharma this was quite a while ago. But if I remember correctly It was some weird quark.  After removing and re-adding on a different machine it seemed to work correctly. I don't know how it got in this state originally.